# Деструктурирование объекта. Ликбез

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Задача: Лаконично (используя деструктуризацию), "разбить" передаваемый в функцию-конструктор объект на <s>переменные</s> свойства для новых экземпляров.
Иными словами, почему нижеприведенный пример кода неправильный?

```
class Menu {
  constructor(options = {}) {
    {
      title: this.title = 'Empty'
    } = options; // (*)
  }
}

const menu = new Menu();
```

К примеру, если бы строка `(*)` была такой: `let {title: t = 'Empty'} = options;`, то ошибки не будет, однако, это не избавить от писанины длинной вереницы присваиваний, наподобие: `this.title = options.title || 'Empty' //...`

Comment: Текста ошибки явно не хватает для полноты картины

Comment: @vas у нас тут астрономическое количество плохих вопросов, большинство из них удалено. Отвечать на них едкими комментариями долго и утомительно, можно поставить минус и идти дальше. Репутации это не стоит.

Comment: @vas, почему вы думаете. что вариант -`let {title: t = 'Empty'} = options;` - не работает?

Comment: @vas, повзрослейте уже наконец и почитайте хоть что-нибудь о современном JS. ES6 позволяет делать и не такое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что в инструкции: `{title: this.title = 'Empty'} = options;` интерпретатор левую часть воспринимает, как блок инструкций, и соответсвенно не может произвести операцию присваивания. 
Наверное, это тонкий момент, но в основном потоке кода, деструктуризация должна являться частью выражения, например, `let {title: t = 'Empty'} = options;`
В том случае, если переменные уже объявлены выше, или как в этом случае, идёт обращение к свойствам объекта, можно попробовать так:

```
    function Menu(options = {}) {
      ({title: this.title = 'Empty'} = options); // (*) 
    }

    const menu = new Menu();
```

Теперь строка `(*)` заключена в круглые скобки, а фигурные интерпретируются так, как и было задумано.

Comment: Спасибо, что опубликовали ответ )